# video driver crash(blackscreen) with multiple live streams

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

My computer specs:
http://cappon.org/specs.html

I have 4 screens connected 3 monitors 1 tv.
I have 3 screens with chrome browsers of witch 1 runs shinobi with 4 cameras.
1 Edge browser to stream netflix/emby/tvapp

On occasion the whole display will crash to black screen. It seems to happen when I open a video stream in one of the chrome browsers (youtube or other) although I cannot consistently recreate it.

Anyone have an idea whats happening ?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem (GPU)

Comment: You would think so but its not. I might have resolved it by running all stream from just one browser it might be that Edge and chrome conflict. Although why I don't know.

Comment: Edge and Chrome absolutely are not conflicting you identified a red herring causation

Comment: You cannot know that for a fact. Noir can I. But the fact is no more crashes while streaming from just one browser.